# C 64-bit loop performance on x86

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, 64-bit

I needed an Internet Checksum function (one's complement checksum) for some IPv4 ICMP processing code using raw sockets and I've stumbled on behaviour I can't explain on a 64-bit Intel processor (using gcc 4.8.2). I was wondering if anybody could shed some light on it.

I implemented a first checksum function using a 32-bit accumulator and performing 16-bit sums. Then I implemented the same using a 64-bit accumulator and 32-bit sums, thinking that less sums would result in faster execution. The result is that the first implementation runs twice as fast as the second (with O3 optimisation). I simply can't figure out why...

The code below doesn't actually perform accurate checksums (I've simplified it) but illustrates the problem. Both compiled as 64-bit running on 64-bit native platform (LP64: short 16-bit, int 32-bit, long 64-bit, pointers 64-bit).

1. 32-bit accumulator and 16-bit sums

   ```
   unsigned short
   cksum_16_le(unsigned char* data, size_t size)
   {
       unsigned short word;
       unsigned int sum = 0;
       unsigned int i;

       for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i += 2)
           sum += *((unsigned short*) (data + i));

       sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
       sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);

       return ~sum;
   }
   ```

50,000 function calls over the same 10k data: ~1.1 seconds.

1. 64-bit accumulator and 32-bit sums

   ```
   unsigned short
   cksum_32_le(unsigned char* data, size_t size)
   {
       unsigned long word;
       unsigned long sum = 0;
       unsigned int i;

       for(i = 0; i < size - 3; i += 4)
           sum += *((unsigned int*) (data + i));

       sum = (sum & 0xffffffff) + (sum >> 32);
       sum = (sum & 0xffffffff) + (sum >> 32);
       sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
       sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);

       return ~sum;
   }
   ```

50,000 function calls over the same 10k data: ~2.2 seconds.

**Update:**

It seems that the issue is due to hardware. Running memory diags revealed occasional bus parity errors (not sure why this would affect the 32-bit version more than the 16-bit version, but there you go). The code runs as expected on other servers. Will delete the question within the next few hours (being hardware related, it is not particularly useful anymore).

**Final update:**

Interestingly, replacing the `for` loops with `while` loops and compiling with O3 optimisation (shown below for the 64-bit accumulator case) gets both the 32-bit and 64-bit accumulator cases to run at identical speeds. This is because compiler performs some loop unrolling (oddly, it does not unroll the `for` loop) and performs the summing using `mmx` registers...

```
uint64_t sum = 0;
const uint32_t* dptr = (const uint32_t*) data;

while (size > 3)
{
    sum += (uint32_t) *dptr++;
    size -= 4;
}
```

Comment: If it's 50,000 loops for the 32/16 bit case, why isn't it 25,000 loops for the 64/32 bit case?

Comment: meant: 50000 iterations of the function. Will update the question.

Comment: Have you tried disassembling it and looking at what these each turn into?

Comment: Shall we assume the original buffer is properly paragraph-aligned in *both* examples?

Comment: I did try to look at the assembly. It looks pretty much identical in both cases. And the data buffer is 64-bit aligned (allocated with posix_memalign).

Comment: is the 64 bit version running in 64 bit mode (did you change the project parameters or command line options to specify 64 bit mode)? If not, then it's using a pair of 32 bit registers to handle a long long int.

Comment: both compiled in 64-bit mode...

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/uPy6Kk), though admittedly I prefer the timing from C++11's chromo lib as its so damn easy to use.

Comment: Well, that got me thinking... just tried on three other servers and getting the expected result. Might be hardware related, guess it's time to run some hw diags.

Comment: did you assure that `data` is properly aligned? If it is 2-byte aligned then the int version's performance would be affected

Comment: Using mmx or not depends on the loop control variable, in the `for` it grows while in the loop it decreases its value, and there is an assembly instruction to test-if-zero-then-jump.

Comment: What's the alignment of the `data` pointer? I can imagine a situation where `data` often has a remainder of 2 when divided by 4 - accessing a 2-byte data element at such an address might be faster than a 4-byte element. If `data` has no alignment restrictions, this may happen 25% of time, which is statistically significant.

Comment: Which processor are you using? if it's HW related then it may be important

Comment: to be clear, `sum += *((unsigned int*) (data + i));` causes undefined behaviour if `data + i` is not correctly aligned for `unsigned int`.  (Also if `size <= 3` it is UB). In your test, ensure that the data is correctly aligned (e.g. put it at the start of some malloc'd space)

Comment: I'd also suggest using fixed-width types to avoid any ambiguity about type sizes, i.e. `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`, etc.

Comment: Also try making your function accept `unsigned int *` ; perhaps in the `char *` version the compiler decides to generate less optimum code because it cannot be sure whether you've passed in an aligned pointer or not

Comment: Regarding the loop optimizations, this may be an interesting read: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: You should really investigate what it compiles to and update this question. I am convinced that if you look into this, you will have your answer

Comment: If you're on linux, the perf tool may be able to shed some light on the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue like this before; I couldn't find any issues in either of our code. BUT what worked for me was changing the compiler.

My guess is that GCC is writing deprecated Assembly.

If you can decompile your application we could shed more light on the issue but there just isn't enough information to go on here.

When I decompiled my code what I found is that it was rewriting an entire method several times. but that might just be for me.

Hope this helped you, there is little to no information about this anywhere.

If I had to guess I would agree with Learner, I am pretty certain that the decompiled code would point to the for loop. I am very interested with this issue so please comment back.

Comment: Please, "deprecated". Not "depreciated".

Answer (score 0):

Probable answer: "i < size - 1" condition can be compiled and executed more efficiently than "i < size - 3". First one requires just a decrement instruction instead of the other which requires a constant 3 to also be loaded somewhere. This calculation is executed with every iteration. You should store the result of this calculation elsewhere.

This has nothing to do with the while loop. When you rewrote the while loop you changed the iteration condition too and eliminated the cause above.

I would also prefer doing the type casting outside the loop, but that also reveals one restriction - your data must

Answer (score 0):

Are you making the compiler's job difficult. In the inner loop you're calculating the byte offset yourself by your choice of index stride and the cast. This might be preventing loop unrolling or any other optimization that tries to assume alignment. Might also not be letting the compiler use addressing modes and going out to calculate the effective address itself (or LEA it).

If i were doing this,  I'd cast the data pointer at the top of the loop to your stride type and increment your loop counter by 1.  The compiler might be a little happier.

Answer (score -1):

I think it cannot unroll the "for" loop because of the cast from char* to unsigned int *. Type casts often prevent the compiler from optimizing the code, because a perfect alias analysis cannot be made in this case. If you first declare an additional local pointer to cast your "data" pointer before the loop, so that there isn't any cast in the loop, the compiler should be able to optimize the "for" loop.

Answer (score -3):

```
sum += *((unsigned int*) (data + i));
```

I dont like such a cast in

> 64-bit accumulator and 32-bit sums

since you wrote :

> Both compiled as 64-bit running on 64-bit native platform (LP64: short 16-bit, int 32-bit, long >64-bit, pointers 64-bit).

I would suggest to use (unsigned long*). Some people advised to check in disassembled code what going on in reality. I think it's because of your int* cast with long accumulator.

What about without O2<>O3 flag? Could you show out what is the speed in normal compilation mode?

Comment: The whole point of the program is to sum 32-bit values. Changing the cast to read 64-bit values would give an incorrect result.

Comment: Then it is normal. As was commented by others it is padding issue. Also if ur integers are only 32bit large saving/adding them two 64bit will need additional operations/checks for correct result, especially when number grows out of 32bit.